# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' -python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python 3 and the code in line 42 is causing the problem

> line 42, in  print
>   ('Retrieved',len(data),'characters',data[:20].replace('\n',' '))
>   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

In my program line-42 is

```
 print ('Retrieved',len(data),'characters',data[:20].replace('\n',' '))
```

I will greatly appreciate your help.

below is the full colde:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import sqlite3
import json
import time
import ssl

# If you are in China use this URL:
# serviceurl = "http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?"
serviceurl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

# Deal with SSL certificate anomalies Python > 2.7
# scontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
scontext = None

conn = sqlite3.connect('geodata.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Locations (address TEXT, geodata TEXT)''')

fh = open("where.data", encoding="utf-8")
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if count > 200 : break
    address = line.strip()
    print ('')
    cur.execute("SELECT geodata FROM Locations WHERE address= ?", ((address), ))

    try:
        data = cur.fetchone()[0]
        print ("Found in database ",address)
        continue
    except:
        pass

    print ('Resolving', address)
    url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({"sensor":"false", "address": address})
    print ('Retrieving', url)
    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=scontext)
    data = uh.read()
    print ('Retrieved',len(data),'characters',data[:20].replace('\n',' '))
    count = count + 1
    try: 
        js = json.loads(str(data))
        # print js  # We print in case unicode causes an error
    except: 
        continue

    if 'status' not in js or (js['status'] != 'OK' and js['status'] != 'ZERO_RESULTS') : 
        print ('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')
        print (data)
        break

    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Locations (address, geodata) 
            VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( buffer(address),buffer(data) ) )
    conn.commit() 
    time.sleep(1)

print ("Run geodump.py to read the data from the database so you can visualize it on a map.")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted with the below code:

print ('Retrieved',len(data),'characters',data[:20].decode().replace('\n',' '))